# How to ignore field itself while creating rule for two different DB table

Tags: laravel

I have a form and getting input values. One of the input field is `email`. I need to check that email is unique in two different table but need to allow the value itself in both table. Tried almost all combinations, but couldn't sort it out.

```
$rules = [
    'email' => "required|unique:admins|unique:vendors,email,$id",
];
```

The code above works but gives warning that `Email has already been taken`. But when I use one table only it works as expected. Maybe someone could help me with that, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably easiest achieved with a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) where you manually confirm the email is unique in each table.

Comment: *"but need to allow the value itself in both table..."* when would you allow that, after validating that the email being **not found** in **both tables** or you can accept the email if it is **found** in **both tables** ? If my question is not understandable, you may tell us the cases when an email should pass the validation.

Comment: if the existing email is at least one of the table, then allow and don't throw error. if not found in any of them not throw error as it is unique. error only happens is the email is not existing one but has used by different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a good use case for [`Custom Validation Rules using Closures`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-closures). Basically, instead of using a bunch of `unique` rules, you'll simply have a `function` (`closure`) where you do your validation logic that decides whether to accept or decline the input.

```
$rules = [
    /** added "email" rule to tell Laravel that we expect an email address */
    'email' => ['required', 'email', function (string $attribute, string $value, Closure $fail) {
        /** a function that checks whether an "email" exists in a "table" or not */
        $existsInTableFN = fn(string $table): bool => DB::table($table)->where($attribute, $value)->exists();

        /**
         * the below condition means that the validation will FAIL
         * if the "email" is found in one table but doesn't exist in the other
         */
        if ($existsInTableFN('admins') !== $existsInTableFN('vendors'))
            $fail('Email address already taken.'); /** laravel will take care of the rest if the above condition is met */
    }]
];
```

**Summary:**

the above `closure` rule will only accept an email if:

1. it doesn't exist in both tables
2. OR does exist in both of them

In other words, the `closure` rule will fail:

- if it finds the submitted email in one table
- but it doesn't find it (the submitted email) in the other table